# If someone decompiles your android app, can they see the signed certificate?

Tags: android

If someone decompiles your .apk file can they then somehow view your signed certificate and/or SHA1?

The reason I ask is I understand it is not wise to place things like a secret key to a restful API in your Android code because someone can decompile the .apk and then view the key in plain text. This got me thinking - what other sensitive information might decompiling reveal? Especially since some API's use the SHA1 of your app to authenticate your app and ensure only it is allowed to invoke the API methods.

Comment: `the SHA1 of your app to authenticate your app` who does that?

Comment: @njzk2: Many of the Play Services APIs. Any of those that you have to register your SHA1 of your signing key to get an API key are presumably doing so for a reason.

Comment: @njzk2 Google Cloud Endpoints for example

Comment: thanks for clarifying. It is the SHA1 of the signing key, not of the app.

Comment: people can view it, but not use it.

Comment: because it is generated from the signing certificate, which remains private, and because it is not valid on an app that is signed with a different certificate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every APKs are signed during build process.  In debug builds, it is signed using debug keys and to sign in release mode, you have to [setup keys](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/tools/publishing/app-signing.html).

Generally speaking, signing allows one to validate the source of the document, in this case APK. It typically has below steps:

1. You calculate hash of a document to be protected.
2. You encrypt the hash using a private key.
3. You embed the hash of the document inside it (in case of Android, it is META-INF/CERT.SF)
4. You distribute document along with public key (in case of Android, it is META-INF/CERT.RSA)

The receiver of document can recompute the hash of the document, and match it with the hash computed at the time of document creation by decrypting the signature using the public key.

The hash value is typically SHA-1 hash.  And it is no secret, as it is required to validate the authenticity of document.

Unfortunately, this mechanism cannot be used to protect any secrets.  The signature is used for proving the data authenticity and not to protect secrets.

As far as protecting keys of REST API is concerned, it is certainly not a good idea to save the keys in the APK, as de-compilers can look it up.

Using [code obfuscators](https://www.guardsquare.com/dexguard) can provide  you certain degree of protection against decompilers.

Another technique one can apply is something like below:

1. Have a login facility for the app.
2. On successful login, return the API key as response to app.  Ensure you use `https` for the login API
3. Keep API key in memory and use it when needed.

Comment: I very much like your technique on returning the API key as a response to the app and storing it in memory!

Comment: @Wand Maker: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but is it possible to redo steps 3 and 4 (from your top-most list), replacing the signed hash and public key with a rogue signature and its corresponding public key? Usually the public key is obtained through a different communication channel, which means that if the signature has been replaced with a rogue signature, the verification will fail when the legitimate public key is used.

Comment: @JanusVarmarken  Theoretically it should be possible to sign with different key.  But one cannot distribute that version of app from the same developer's play store page, so person downloading need to be aware of which is genuine app.

Comment: @WandMaker doesn't https solution have its flaws? Decompiling the app would get access to login API endpoint, which with a valid user would return the API key. Perhaps it is better to generate a unique key for each user with a combination of a hash and some dynamic salt. Thanks for your comment I found it very useful

Answer (score 2):

> If someone decompiles your .apk file can they then somehow view your signed certificate and/or SHA1?

You do not need to decompile to get the SHA1 (or other hashes) of the public key corresponding to the private key that you used to sign the APK. That is part of the APK itself and can be retrieved with a bit of Java code in another app.

Comment: So basically that private key will not be ever revealed, even if the .apk is decompiled?

Comment: @MicroR: Right. The private key is on your hard drive. The public key is in the APK.